# Desperately seeking examples of a pure JS (ES5) & Vue data-driven page generator

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am seeking pointers to documentation or example code for the creation of a page generator, predominantly targeting forms but possibly also non-form pages.

It must be:

- Vue based (because of the major frameworks, Vue says it can be added progressively)
- ES5 only - no ES6, Webpack, NPM, or similar build process etc - just pure JS.
- Capable of generating full pages, not just form inputs

The concept is to make a data driven page generator where the flow is:

- the code is bootstrapped into life in the browser
- it gets the layout of the page from a server via ajax
- it renders the page using Vue controls (deliberately avoiding the term 'components' but that can be a part of the solution - render functions?)
- if it's a form there is some validation then the users data when submitted is available for munging into a package to be sent to the server. I am confident on this point at least.
- some simple routing mechanism can translate a route to a key for fetching the data-driven layout of the target 'page'... then rinse and repeat.

The reason for ES5-only and no webpack / build process is to avoid dependencies.

From my own research I have found one candidate in

- [Reef](https://github.com/cferdinandi/reef) - A lightweight library for creating reactive, state-based components and UI.

Can anyone point me toward others?

**[For those hovering over the 'flag-to-close' button]**

I realise this is a broad and ill-defined question however I think it is worthy of remaining because:

- the requirement is real
- I am not seeking subjective answers, I am looking for links to material to give me a starting point from which to build out
- I am not challenging the npm/webpack/build workflow - just seeking a skinny alternative
- there is a cost to NPM packages - see this article [NPM packages: they ain’t free, you know](https://medium.com/@david.gilbertson/npm-packages-they-aint-free-you-know-e3506278314c) which expands on that point
- I will update the question with a working snippet to illustrate the result if I ever find one.

Comment: Looking for tutorials, off-site resources, etc. is off-topic here. Your question might not be too broad or ill-defined, but it is still off-topic IMO.

Comment: Fair play - I hoped I might get something usable before the question gets closed. On the positive side, I did promise to return a working snippet when I find something.